# Error showing while using RestSharp RestClient method

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

My API is calling REST API using RestSharp and Code looks like this

```
    var runRequest = { Contains my JSON}
    var client = new RestClient(".....");
    var request = new RestRequest("....", Method.Post);
    string AuthHeader = "...";

    request.AddParameter("application/json", runRequest, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthHeader, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
    var response = client.Execute(request); <---- {Red line showing under client}
    return Ok(response);
```

Error

[image]

Because of that red line, I am not able to run my program. Can somebody please tell what the issue can be ?

Thank you

Comment: Not that I use RestSharp, but I think you are looking for `ExecuteAsync`. When you type "client.   ", what does Visual Studio show you in intellisense as available methods?

Comment: When i type client, intelligence show RestClient client

Comment: okay, So "client." intelligence gives me ExecuteAsync , ExecuteGetAsync etc. But not Execute.

Comment: The error is gone because ExecuteAsync takes a RestRequest argument. Now you have to make sure to handle the async nature correctly, by awaiting it.

Comment: But I don't want to use async nature, then what should I do?

Comment: You can block on the call by doing `client.Execute(request).Result`. At best this will be an abuse of async benefits, at worst you risk deadlocking a thread. If it is at all an option, I suggest refactoring for async.

Comment: @Crowcoder Okay I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the latest RestSharp version. All the sync methods were deprecated as RestSharp uses `HttpClient` under the hood, and `HttpClient` doesn't have any sync overloads, everything is async.

You can find a list of changed or deprecated members of `RestClient` in the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference).

Comment: Thanks. Now I understood. Can you also please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568629/getting-error-while-creating-job-from-jobs-api